# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. I added a property and got this error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I don't understand why i got this error, I just added a new foreign key property to Rest model and it doesn't work:

**Error**

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use exercises.set() instead.
```

I don't know if the name "rest" is causing I already changed the name of the property but I can't make it work.

**models.py**

```
class Routine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
class Workout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    routine = models.ForeignKey(Routine, related_name='workouts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Exercise(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField()
    video_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, related_name='exercises', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Rest(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, related_name='rests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    routine = models.ForeignKey(Routine, related_name='rests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exercises = ExerciseSerializer(many=True)
    rests = RestSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'creation_date', 'exercises', 'rests']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        exercises_data = validated_data.pop('exercises')
        rests_data = validated_data.pop('rests')
        workout = Workout.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        for exercise_data in exercises_data:
            Exercise.objects.create(workout=workout, **exercise_data)

        for rest_data in rests_data:
            Rest.objects.create(workout=workout, **rest_data)

        return workout

class RoutineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    workouts = WorkoutSerializer(many=True)
    rests = RestSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Routine
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'creation_date', 'workouts', 'rests']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        workouts_data = validated_data.pop('workouts')
        rests_data = validated_data.pop('rests')
        
        routine = Routine.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for workout_data in workouts_data:
            Workout.objects.create(routine=routine, **workout_data)

        for rest_data in rests_data:
            Rest.objects.create(routine=routine, **rest_data)

        return routine
```

Comment: Can you add what a sample payload that you send to the api and related views

Comment: Sure, here it is:
{
    "name": "Routine Example",
    "workouts": [
        {
            "name": "Workout Example",
            "exercises": [
                {
                    "index": 0,
                    "video_url": "https://trycombine.com/posts/self-weak-unowned/"
                }
            ],
            "rests": [
                {
                    "index": 1,
                    "duration": 60
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "rests": [
        {
        "index": 0,
        "duration": 60
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Also this is the view:
class WorkoutViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Workout.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WorkoutSerializer

class ExerciseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Exercise.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExerciseSerializer

class RestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rest.objects.all()
    serializers_class = RestSerializer